# Obtener value Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Como podria obtner el value de la seccion <> utilizando selenium para realizar un test y comprobar siempre el nombre correo no consigo realizarlo con selenium nunca obtengo el valor

```
<font color="#75D246">Prueba Selenium</font>
```

El valor siempre esta en esta etiqueta.

```
texto = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@font="color="#75D246""]')
```

print(texto)

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu código de intento, el código html que rodea a esa etiqueta font, o la URL de la página de donde quieres hacer el scraping

Comment: claro lo muestro si sera un disparate lo que tengo

Comment: Si la página es generada dinámicamente puede ser necesario esperar la aparicion del elemento usando `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@font="color="#75D246""]"))` dentro un bloque `try` aunque la referencia font y color no es fácilmente distinguible porque puede haber múltiples elementos iguales.
    )

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera debería funcionar:

```
texto = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@font="color="#75D246""]').text
```